# Repairing the world after the events of 24/7

Tags: the-sandman

Specifically in the Netflix adaptation of *The Sandman*, the events in the diner in episode 5 are shown to have global effects; newscasts in the diner mention this, the electricity goes out, and we see an overturned, flaming car. What, if anything, does Dream do to repair the world before episode 6? Are Judy and all the others who died brought back to life?

Comment: No. The dead stay dead

Comment: I doubt Dream can even reverse time or revive the dead.